# How to ask user for number of times to roll a 6 sided dice?

Tags: java, dice

How do I ask a user how many 6 sided dice to roll to add them to their given offset?

I have one 6 sided die rolling and being added to the given offset but need to add user input D6s.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Fun

{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
      Random rand = new Random();



      System.out.print("How many dice do you want to roll?");
      int D6 = scan.nextInt();


      System.out.print("What would you like your offset to be?");
      int offset = scan.nextInt();

      int roll= rand.nextInt(6)+1;
      int total= roll+offset;

      System.out.print("The result of rolling "+D6+"D6+"+offset+" is "       +total);

}
}
```

Comment: What is `offset` supposed to accomplish here?

Comment: I wont lie to you it is for an assignment I believe to show I know how to add things I suppose lol, but the last part of the assignment I cannot figure out is how to roll multiple dies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple for loop which iterates D6 number of times and adds up the numbers, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();

    System.out.print("How many dice do you want to roll?");
    int D6 = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("What would you like your offset to be?");
    int offset = scan.nextInt();

    int total = 0;

    for(int i=0 ; i<D6 ; i++){
        int number = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        System.out.println("Rolled " + number);
        total += number;
    }

    total = total + offset;

    System.out.print("The result of rolling " + D6 + "D6+" + offset + " is " + total);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already asked the user how many times they want to roll, at this point you can use a `for` loop:

```
System.out.print("How many dice do you want to roll?");
int D6 = scan.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < D6; i++) { //This will roll the specified amount of times
    //Rest of code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can roll the dice multiple times by a for-loop:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Felcan_A02Q3{
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
  Random rand = new Random();



  System.out.print("How many dice do you want to roll?");
  int D6 = scan.nextInt();


  System.out.print("What would you like your offset to be?");
  int offset = scan.nextInt();

  int total = offset; //the value of total is set to the same as offset
  for(int x = 0; x < D6; x++){ //this loop repeats as often as the value of D6 is
    total =+ rand.nextInt(6)+1; //here every roll of the dice is added to the total value
  }

  System.out.print("The result of rolling "+D6+"D6+"+offset+" is "       +total);

}
}
```

This is how it would look applied to your code